# >= won't work correctly

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x

```
contract MyIfElse {
    uint256 public revealState = 0;
    bool public isNowRevealed = false;

    function addToRevealState () private {
        revealState++;
    }

    function isRevealed () public {
        if (revealState >= 10){
            isNowRevealed = true;
            addToRevealState();
        }else{
            addToRevealState();
        }
    }
}
```

When the `revealState()` is called,  `addToRevealstate()` gets triggered as intended because the `if else` statement hasn't been met.

The problems occurs when the `revealState` = 10. The `isNowReveal` bool does not update the state to `true`. Only after `revealState` = 11 will the state be updated to `true`.

Is there an indexing issue I'm not taking into account?

Comment: Are you saying that when `revealState` is `10`, calling `isRevealed` does not set `isNowRevealed` to `true`?

Comment: Correct. I have to call it again, which means `realState` is now 11 before `isNowRevealed` turns `true`.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you're mixing up the ordering here. `revealState` will _turn_ 11 when `isNowRevealed` turns `true`, but it is `10` when the transaction that flips `isNowRevealed` to `true` begins!

So you have a state like this, where each new state is the result of a call to `isRevealed`
(0, false) -> ... -> (9, false) -> (10, false) -> (11, true).

The `true` only shows up when `revealState` is `11` because you always increment `revealState` after setting `isNowRevealed` to `true`. But the flip happens when `revealState` is `10`.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks mate. As you probably guess I'm rather new. Thank you so much for taking some time to help me. So sometimes is a simple ordering problem.

Comment: No worries! This behaviour definitely can feel confusing sometimes! I'll throw my comment in an answer so that this question doesn't show up as "unanswered" :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up the ordering here. `revealState` will turn `11` when `isNowRevealed` turns `true`, but it is `10` when the transaction that flips `isNowRevealed` to `true` begins!

So you have a state like this, where each new state is the result of a call to `isRevealed`:

> `(0, false) -> ... -> (9, false) -> (10, false) -> (11, true)`

The true only shows up when `revealState` is `11` because you always increment `revealState` after setting `isNowRevealed` to `true`. But the flip happens when `revealState` is `10`.